# Deploying a web project inside of a Liferay Portlet

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, iframe, liferay

**Good Morning SO!**

I'm playing around with Liferay in Eclipse right now and have a few simple questions.

I have a dynamic web project that I've created in Eclipse. It's just a simple `html` page that literally just says "Hello" in the body and nothing else.

What I'm wondering is how would I deploy this web project inside of a new Liferay portlet? 
Should I use the iFrame portlet with the `src` pointing to the url in my localhost?

I've also heard that creating an iFrame in my **view.jsp** with the `src` pointing to the root folder of my project would work also, but I couldn't get it to.

Any experienced Liferayer should be able to answer this in a snap. **Upvotes Await!** :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both approaches you mention should work.

Be aware that by default, Liferay runs in the ROOT context of the servlet container.  So it completely handles all requests on the host/port it is running on.  So, assuming both these Liferay and your little app are running on localhost, they need to be on different ports.  Or, of course, run them on separate hosts.